# Automatic rebalance shards on Solrcloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Simple question, is there any way to automatically rebalance the shard replicas in SolrCloud? For example, I have a two node cluster and I create a collection with replica number 2. At the time of the creation though, only one node is up, so both replicas are created at the same node. However, I would like for the second replica to be moved to the second node, whenever it becomes available.

I am lost with the Solr documentation but I could not find any obvious solution to this.

I saw that there is an API called [solrcloud-rebalance-api](https://github.com/bloomreach/solrcloud-rebalance-api) but I don't think it is publicly available.

Comment: Me too checking for same. pls Let me know if you have found any way.

Comment: I had to manually create an extra replica and remove the old one. Alternatively, (but I am not sure), but you can check the `autoAddReplicas' in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+HDFS#RunningSolronHDFS-autoAddReplicasSettings.